# System configuration file in ColdFusion

Tags: coldfusion, tfs

I am using Team Foundation Server (TFS) to check in/out my ColdFusion files (cfm files). We have a .config file in case of .Net projects that contains all system configurations. My question is do we have any such file in ColdFusion. Is it Application.cfm?

Answer (score 1):

Older ColdFusion sites use `application.cfm` newer ones use `application.cfc`

Many ColdFusion frameworks use additional xml files for their config.

Last but not least, the ColdFusion administrator stores the information database connections.

I am developing in a similar TFS / Visual Studio environment. Thus far we don't store any the ColdFusion environments files in version control, but I could see that being mandated someday.

These files exist in `{cf-root}\lib\neo-*.xml`